# Get the latest input from the model

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I wanna the last input to `bid_price` to be received in the `Bid_info` model and attributed to `bid_max`, however it gives this error

> earliest() and latest() require either fields as positional arguments or 'get_latest_by' in the model's Meta.

views:

```
@login_required
def page_product(request, productid):
    bid_max = Bid_info.objects.filter(pk=productid).latest()
    context={
        'bid_max' : bid_max      
    }
return render(request, 'auctions/page_product.html', context)
```

html:

```
<p> final price = {{bid_max}} </p>
```

models:

```
class Bid_info(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    seller = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="seller")
    bid_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    checkclose = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    winner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, 
                                                                blank=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is what you use to order. You can use the primary key, but that is often a tricky choice: the primary key is not per se assigned in a linear manner.

If you want to get the bid with the largest `bid_price`, you use:

```
@login_required
def page_product(request, productid):
    bid_max = Bid_info.objects.filter(product_id=productid).latest('bid_price')
    context = {'bid_max': bid_max}
    return render(request, 'auctions/page_product.html', context)
```

This will thus return the `Bid_info` object for the product with the highest `bid_price`.

---

> **Note**: Models in Django are written in *PascalCase*, not *snake_case*,
> so you might want to rename the model from <s>`Bid_info`</s> to `BidInfo`.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: However, when a new product is defined, this error is displayed:`Bid_info matching query does not exist.`

Comment: @zahra: well there is no `Bid_info` for that bid. You can use `Bid_info.filter(product_id=productid).order_by('bid_price').last()` to get the last one, or `None` if there is no such `Bid_info`.

Comment: It was fixed with a try loop. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By using

```
bid_max = Bid_info.objects.filter(pk=productid).latest()
```

only give you 1 object, cause you use "pk" to filter. Which is unique for every object. So you can't access latest, last, frist.

Use

```
p = Article.objects.filter(some_field=value).order_by("bid_price").first() 


Or

p = Article.objects.all().order_by("bid_price").first()
```

to get the frist object.

Use

```
p = Article.objects.filter(some_field=value).order_by("bid_price").last() 


Or

Or

p = Article.objects.all().order_by("bid_price").last()
```

to get the last object.